# Problemas con carga de datos con ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, postgresql

Tengo un problema con la carga de datos mediante ajax, estoy tratando de pasar un dato pero es como si mi ajax no le pasara el dato de la variable, he intentado eliminando algo de codigo y me a funcionado pero sin el filtro que deseo, elimine esta parte:

```
$vessel_name = $_POST['vessel_name']; 
if($vessel_name != ''){ 
   if(!$dbconn){
      die("<br/>Sin conexi&oacute;n.");
}
```

Y asi como nada funciona, me carga los datos de la tabla con el `ajax` pero sin el filtro que requiero, adjunto el codigo donde solicito y el codigo de mi `php` donde esta la consulta:

Codigo que solicita:

```
<strong><div class='hr-or my-5'></div></strong>

<p class="h3 my-4">Seleccione el buque al cual quiere dar seguimiento.</p>
<select class="btn btn-secondary btn-md btn-block my-3 text-center" id="vessel">
    <?php
    $query = 'SELECT DISTINCT "VESSEL_NAME" from vessel_complete ORDER BY "VESSEL_NAME" ASC';
    $result = pg_query($dbconn, $query);
    echo '<option value="0"> -- Seleccione un buque -- </option>';
    while($row = pg_fetch_row($result)){
        echo '<option class="text-center" value="'.$row[0].'">'.$row[0].'</option>';
    }

    ?>
</select>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <select disable="" class="btn btn-primary btn-md btn-block my-3 text-center" id="fecha" disable="">
                <option value="">-- Seleccione una fecha --</option>
            </select>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    var fecha = $('#fecha');
                    var fecha_sel = $('#fecha_sel');

                    $('#vessel').change(function(){
                        var vessel_name = $(this).val();

                        if (vessel_name !== '') {
                            $.ajax({
                                data: {"vessel_name":vessel_name},
                                dataType: 'html',
                                type: 'POST',
                                url: 'consultas.php'
                            }).done(function(data){
                                fecha.html(data);
                                fecha.prop('disable', false);
                            });
                        }else{
                            fecha.val('');
                            fecha.prop('disable', true);
                        }
                    });
                });
```

Codigo que consulta:

```
<?php
 require 'conexion/conexion.php'; 
 $vessel_name = $_POST['vessel_name']; 
 if($vessel_name != ''){ 
     if(!$dbconn){
        die("<br/>Sin conexi&oacute;n.");
      }
 $sql = 'SELECT "TIMESTAMP_UTC1", "TIMESTAMP_UTC2" FROM vessel_complete 
 WHERE "VESSEL_NAME" = '.$vessel_name.' ORDER BY "TIMESTAMP_UTC1" ASC';  
 $query2 = pg_query($dbconn, $sql);


 }
 ?>

 <option value="">-- Seleccione --</option>
 <?php
 while($row2 = pg_fetch_row($query2)){
 echo '<option class="text-center" value="'.$row2[0].'">'.$row2[0].'</option>';
 }
 pg_close($dbconn);
 ?>
```

Adjunto una foto con el select que lleno pero con datos no filtrados:

[image: Imagen de muestra]

Comment: y qué error te sale?

Comment: No tira error, simplemente no me trae los valores.

Comment: has revisado la consola? que trae de respuesta cuando no muestra datos la llamada a consultas.php?

Comment: ya he revisado la consola como te digo, no muestra nada incorrecto.

Comment: Pero pon que te regresa la llamada , en red debe venir la llamada a consultas.php, debe regresar algo.

Comment: He encontrado el problema, si me lo esta llevando a consultas.php el problema es que al momento de ponerlo en el query queda sin comilas simples que son necesarias en un string.